# What is the name for a vector with a single non-zero component?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, convention

> What do you call a vector with a single component, e.g. $[a, 0, ..., 0]$ or $[0, b, 0, ..., 0]$, where $a, b$ are any non-zero number?

I'd like the language to differentiate from a vector with many components, e.g. $[a, b, 0, c, 0]$.

Comment: Still vectors, but they are parallel to your coordinate axes.

Comment: Some vectors of that form are called standard basis vectors, such as $\vec{i}=<1,0,0>$.

Comment: Right, I'm interested in the general term, when the component is not necessarily equal to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a single non-zero component, as do, e.g., $[a, 0, 0, . . ., o]$, $[0, b, 0, . . ., 0]$, etc., is a *basis-dependent* property, so it does not really reflect the coordinate independence which makes many abstract vector methods so powerful.  It is easy to see that, under a suitable change of basis, these vectors will no longer have exactly one non-zero component.  So, I think I would adopt a somewhat prosaic description, such as ***vectors with a single nonzero component in the such-and-such basis***; here you can think of ***"such-and-such basis"*** as a verbal variable ranging over the domain consisting of any and all bases for the vector space under consideration! ;)

The notion of standard basis vectors, as mentioned by Daniel Rust in his answer, can be a helpful one here, but in many instances it is not clear exactly what the standard basis is; for example, when we are dealing with $\Bbb F^n$ for some field $\Bbb F$, the standard is clear: $[1, 0, 0, . . . , 0]$, $[0, 1, 0, . . . , 0]$ etc.  But in some contexts, there really is no standard; I am thinking here of bases for the tangent spaces on a manifold; this is a situation is which adopting a standard is not necessarily possible or advantageous.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 4):

I would call such vectors '*multiples of the standard basis vectors*'. The standard basis vectors are normally written as $e_i=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,0)$ where the $1$ appears in the $i$-th position, and so the vectors you are considering are equal to $ae_i=(0,0,\ldots,0,a,0,\ldots,0,0)$ for some $a$ and $i$.

Comment: This is exactly what I came to after reading the comment of @SujaanKunalan

Comment: or a *scaled standard-basis vector*

Answer (score 1):

You may call it a *single-entry vector*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-entry_vector

Answer (score 0):

Typically in Machine Learning context they are usually called "One-hot vectors" and they are used to encode which variable gets activated each time, assuming only one can be active.

Comment: But "one-hot" implies that the non-zero entry is equal to $1$, I believe.